# Auth0 (Lock) integration in React native + backend

Tags: reactjs, react-native, auth0

I'm trying to find the best way to integrate Auth0 login into a React Native application. The login widget for React Native works perfectly fine, but I'm kind of confused as to how we get the users also logged in on the backend so they can make requests to modify data. The backend is running on Node (Meteor). Do I have to send the id_token to the backend, and login with auth0 there? I'm kind of confused on how to integrate this for both the app and the backend, so that when the user logs into the mobile application, the backend also knows they're logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the client communicates with the backend, it should send the id_token with the request.  On each request, the backend should validate the token (using a jwt library) to verify that the token has a valid signature and has not expired.  Once validated, the backend will be able to use the user id embedded within the token to perform any authorization rules or business logic it wishes.

Check out [this github project](https://github.com/optune/meteor-auth0-oauth) for an example Meteor auth0 backend.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking something along these lines as well, however to me, it appeared to be quite inefficient to send the token over with every request.

Comment: tokens are not very big unless you add too much to the `scope` option when configuring `lock`.  Tokens on every request is how the web mostly works these days.